# How to change the page numbers displayed in a pdf viewer?

Tags: pdf, page-numbering

I'd like to prepare a LaTeX file of a part of a larger volume, containing for example pages from 50 to 60.  Is there a way to do it so that a pdf viewer does not display "1" but "50" on the first page and so on?  I tried `\setcounter{page}{49}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Simply loading `hyperref` does this for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think about it - of course it works!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved by loading the `hyperref` package. It will store the logical page numbers as page labels in the PDF. This also allows for non-numeric labels like roman numbers for the frontmatter.

Comment: If you don't want `hyperref`'s hyperlinks to show up, load it as `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`. For more details on its various functions, check out the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf).

Comment: Good point!

Since I'm only loading some pages from another pdf using the `pdfpages` package, this is not needed in my case; but thanks anyway for the tip, I (or someone) might need it some day;), and the hyperref manual is rather large...