# How can I set the page number to any needed value?

Tags: page-numbering

I have a seven page long paper which will be assembled with other papers. I know that the first page of my paper will be page 68 in the assembled work. What can i do to tell LaTeX to start counting from 68?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I'm not sure if this question necessarily has anything to do with the `fancyhdr` package, as the mechanism for specifying the page number is independent

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about headers or footers, but rather about page numbering.

Comment: Related, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22909/250119) addresses how to change the page number displayed in the pdf viewer too.

Answer (score 89):

you can usually set the desired page number by `\setcounter{page}{68}`.

there are some commands, e.g. `\chapter`, that may result in an increased page number (see below); in such a case, you should set the value to one less than what you want to start with.

also, be aware that `\chapter` will, by definition, start on an odd-numbered page, and this may result in the page number being increased.  your span starts with an even-numbered page.  if that is a problem, ask for more help.

Comment: At least for scrbook when you set twoside=false, chapters may appear on even pages (which automatically removes the blank pages before chapters as well. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionally_blank_page)

Comment: How to set counter for no page numbers.

Comment: @kaka -- `\thispagestyle{empty)` will remove the page number on the first page, but on other pages it will also remove running heads.  How those are set depends on how the page headings are defined, and not enough is known from this question to answer that reliably.

Answer (score 44):

You can use

```
\setcounter{page}{68}
```

although if you're creating a 'chapter-like' file, then you probably want `\includeonly` as detailed in [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs)

Comment: Aah, you beat me to the answer by about 10 seconds! I'll go ahead and delete mine and upvote yours.

Comment: @Mico you're very kind :) I'll find another of your answers to give you +1