# Combining different knitr files into one

Tags: multiple-files

I have written several documents in `article` class using `knitr`. Each of these files uses different packages, defines its own macros, includes multiple tables and figures, and has its own natbib library. Some include an appendix. Each file used to be a project on its own that now get concatenated.

I would like to combine them into a large overall document with title page and an introduction. Apart from this, each chapter should be "self-contained", except for the page number which should correspond to the large overall document.

I have seen several solutions, such as the `subfile` package and the `\include` command. My understanding is that they can concatenate texts but I wonder whether they can be used in my situation where each file feels like its own world. Ideally, I would want to start a new directory and copy over the relevant .tex (skipping the knitr-step), .bib, and figure files and start a new LaTeX file that includes the title and introduction and then concatenates the projects. However, I wonder which solution is most appropriate for this case.

Comment: Here is a simple solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/how-can-i-set-the-page-number-to-any-needed-value/87528

Comment: I see. Is there really no way of compiling it all at once?

Comment: Do not forget docmute, standalone, combine, subdocs,  and eve maybe minidocument (https://ctan.org/topic/subdocs) but at the end the Frankenstein document really only can have one brain (said it "preamble") and it is up to you ensure that it is the correct one, the one with understand all the transplanted body parts.  As Rstudio  user (I guess) consider use `bookdown`, where this main-child play is done in the Rmarkdown area, but anyway pass to LaTeX  only a  single `.tex` file.