# How can I achieve having logical page numbers shown in acrobat reader?

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, plain-tex

I am using (plain) TeX (not LaTeX or any other ...TeX). I want a pdf file made from my TeX-source/output that is able to have acrobat reader shown *logical page numbers*. My document’s preface page numbering should be displayed like “vi (6 of 123)” and the main part like “2 (12 of 123)” in acrobat reader’s tool bar.

How do i achieve that? Do I have to use `\special`, `pdfTeX`, `dvipdfm(x)`? How do I specify the roman numeral page numbers in the TeX source? Is there a (TeX) macro package for that?

Thanks to all TeX Wizards for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the page numbers displayed in a pdf viewer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22909/how-to-change-the-page-numbers-displayed-in-a-pdf-viewer)

Comment: @MartinSchröder I wouldn't say so; the question has to somehow involve two counters---one for the PDF metadata, and one for the actual output.  I don't (immediately) see how the linked addresses this... :/

Comment: @SeanAllred: Why two counters? The “(_n_ of _N_)” part is implemented directly in Acrobat. The only thing to do here is tell the PDF which number and in which format is displayed on the page. So @MartinSchröder’s link points a duplicate. But I fear it won’t help for plain TeX (as requested here)?!

Comment: @Tobi You're right, it doesn't seem `hyperref` supports plain TeX.  Some people have [suggested](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2009-February/011782.html) Eplain, but I have *zero* experience on that one.  As you said though, the (n of N) bit is traditionally a reader feature, but I think OP is asking for the string itself to be in the PDF?  (I think this needs some more explanation...)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I never used plain TeX so can’t help in this case too …

Comment: Yes, you need `\pdfliteral` with pdfTeX (don't know how to do this with dvipdfmx), and some heavy use of that. The relevant sections of the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) are 12.4.2 (Page Labels) and 7.7.2 (Document Catalog, Key `PageLabels`).

Answer (score 15):

PDF page labels are a data structure in the `/Catalog`, e.g.:

```
/PageLabels <<
  /Nums [
    0 <<
      /P (Title)
    >>
    1 <<
      /S /D
    >>
    3 <<
      /S /A
      /St 7
    >>
  ]
>>
```

This means,

- the first page number (page numbers are zero based) contains a prefix `/P` with string "`Title`".
- The next two pages (2 and 3) are numbered with arabic numbers, starting with `1` (default).
- The last page(s), page 4, is numbered with uppercase letters (LaTeX: `\Alph`) and the numeric values of the page numbers start with seven. Therefore the last page 4 is labeled `G`.

The documentation for PDF page labels can be found in the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

## Analyzing an example with `hyperref`

You can study, how `hyperref` writes the PDF data structures for PDF page labels.

The example hooks into some internals to expose the written PDF data structures, needed for PDF page labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  bookmarks=false,
  pageanchor=false,
]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\print@arg}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{#2}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\x
    \typeout{==> \string#1{\x}}%
  \endgroup
}

% DVI drivers
\@ifdefinable\org@special{%
  \let\org@special\special
  \renewcommand*{\special}[1]{%
    \org@special{#1}%
    \print@arg\special{#1}%
  }%
}

% pdfTeX
\ltx@IfUndefined{pdfcatalog}{%
}{%
  \ifpdf
    \@ifdefinable\org@Hy@PutCatalog{%
      \let\org@Hy@PutCatalog\Hy@PutCatalog
      \def\Hy@PutCatalog#1{%
        \org@Hy@PutCatalog{#1}%
        \print@arg\pdfcatalog{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null
\thispdfpagelabel{Title}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\null
\newpage
\null   
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\setcounter{page}{7}
\null
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Now the console output or the `.log` file contains the data, that can be used for plain TeX.

### pdfTeX/LuaTeX

```
\pdfcatalog{/PageLabels<</Nums[0<</P(Title)>>1<</S/D>>3<</S/A /St 7>>]>>}
```

### XeTeX/dvipdfm(x)

Two compile runs are needed, because the page labels are known at the end of the document and `\special`s cannot be written *after* the last page.

Since many `\special`s are output, the right one needs to be identified, it contains the string `/PageLabels`:

```
\special{pdf:docview <</PageLabels<</Nums[0<</P(Title)>>1<</S/D>>3<</S/A /St 7>>]>>>>}
```

### dvips

Currently two runs are needed. (Perhaps I will reduce it to one in the future, using a common PostScript header file to overcome the `\special` limitation).

Again, the right special is found via searching for `/PageLabels`:

```
\special{ps:SDict begin [ {Catalog} <</PageLabels<</Nums[0<</P(Title)>>1<</S/D>>3<</S/A /St 7>>]>>>> /PUT pdfmark end}
```