# How to restart page numbering the correct way after a report title page

Tags: pdftex, titles, page-breaking, page-numbering, report

I am making a document using the `report` class:

```tex
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\title{My Report}
\author{Ben Z.}
\date{September 8, 2022}

\begin{document}

{ % I previously had this as a `titlepage` environment, but that didn't seem to do anything.
    \let\newpage\relax%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
        This document was made as an MWE for TeX StackExchange.
    \end{center}
}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    Copyleft 2022 Ben Z. No Rights Reserved.
\end{center}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Beginnings}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

\end{document}
```

As you can see if you compile this, I have a title page with a copyleft notice on the reverse of it. The *next* page should be numbered as page 1.

To accomplish this, I tried adding `\setcounter{page}{1}` (I also tried something similar with `\addtocounter`) after the title page, but there were two problems with this:

- When I printed my document double-sided, the pagination got messed up. The title page was on its own sheet of paper, and the copyleft notice was on the front of the next sheet.
- The numbering in Adobe Acrobat was incorrect. As I scrolled through the document, the page number indicator at the top of the screen went 1 → 2 → 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → ...

**Is there a way to change the page number without encountering these two problems?** I do not want page numbers on my title page.

In other documents that I read in Acrobat, I see something like this in the toolbar at the top:

[image: The Adobe Acrobat toolbar. In the place of the current page number, the word "Cover" is present. It is followed by "(1 of 53)."]

**Is there a way to do something like this with pdfLaTeX?**

---

**Note:** Similar questions to this one have been asked, but as far as I know, this is not a duplicate (it is slightly different).

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution comes from a [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128062/161015)'s answer.

It requires loading `hyperref` and adding pdf labels to the first two pages. (Title and Copyleft respectively). They will show in the external pdf viewer with those "numbers".

If `\setcounter{page}{1}` is added before the first chapter then
Chapter 1 (physical page #3 but with a logical page number of 1) will appear in the viewer as page 1 and so on.

[image: c]

[image: d]

This code will produce an eight page document.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\title{My Report}
\author{Ben Z.}
\date{September 8, 2022}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text <<<

\usepackage[
pdfpagelabels=true,
%bookmarks=false,
pageanchor=false,
]{hyperref}% needed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\begin{document}
    
{\let\newpage\relax%
        \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
        \thispdfpagelabel{Title} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \maketitle
        \begin{center}
            This document was made as an MWE for TeX StackExchange.
        \end{center}}

    
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \thispdfpagelabel{Copyleft}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        Copyleft 2022 Ben Z. No Rights Reserved.
    \end{center}
    \cleardoublepage
    
    
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    
    \chapter{Beginnings}
    
    \kant[1-20]
    
\end{document}
```

To print this document double-sided, you need a printer that can do it and use the right paper size.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you add the `bookmarks=false` and `pageanchor=false` options to `hyperref`? I have a feeling that the latter has to do with the `destination with the same identifier` warnings—is there any way to do something about those?

Comment: @Ben Z. You are correct in canceling the warning. Obviously you don't want any other page id's, just the page labels.
I usually set `bookmarks=false` because most of the time I use the package `bookmark` to add bookmarks. For this example it is irrelevant. Thank you for your feedback!