# outputting pdf with page numbers that align to printed?

Tags: luatex, pdf, page-numbering

I have a situation where documents are issued daily, but are compiled into a paper volume at a later date. The page numbers follow on so that the volume is numbered continuously. I'm thinking of generating these in Latex.

Is there a way to make the pdf page number align to the printed page number?

A sample doc is - [Here](https://www.parliament.wa.gov.au/Hansard/hansard.nsf/0/999779E66C6B24554825881E002E6BE7/$File/A41%20S1%2020220405%20All.pdf) Note how your pdf reader says the first page is 1, but it should actually be 1539.

The question is how to have the pdf reporting the actual page number.

However, I do note that I probably need to keep a variable in a file to show what the next Part's page number start should be

EDIT: Turns out a duplicate of [How to change the page numbers displayed in a pdf viewer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22909/how-to-change-the-page-numbers-displayed-in-a-pdf-viewer)

Comment: The question is too vague, but [How can I set the page number to any needed value? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/how-can-i-set-the-page-number-to-any-needed-value) might be what you want.

Comment: (count the number of pages in the previous volumes with whatever tool, then generate a command to start number from that total+1 in the new TeX file)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22909/how-to-change-the-page-numbers-displayed-in-a-pdf-viewer). Loading the hyperref package should be enough to fix this, though it'll only be respected by some (not all) pdf viewers. What are you using?

Comment: thanks @frabjous..maybe put it in as an answer so I can credit you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the hyperref package with the pdfpagelabels option (which is activated by default), it will set page labels in the pdf matching the page counter as represented by `\thepage` in LaTeX for each page.

See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22909/how-to-change-the-page-numbers-displayed-in-a-pdf-viewer).

Page labels will only be respected by some PDF viewers, however.